# How can I intercept normal symbols when using LD_PRELOAD?

Tags: c++, c, linux, ld-preload

`LD_PRELOAD` just can intercept dynamic symbols, is there any way which can intercept the normal symbols?

`nm -D /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so` shows the dynamic symbols. And these symbols can be intercepted by using `LD_PRELOAD`.

But I have no idea how to intercept normal symbols(`nm libc-2.17.so` shows all normal symbols).

eg: `__opendirat` is a normal symbol not a dynamic symbol, I have tried to re-write the function in my own `test.cpp` and used `LD_PRELOAD` to intercept. But there is an error when using `LD_DEBUG`:

```
/lib/libc.so.6: error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: __opendirat (fatal)
```

Comment: `LD_PRELOAD` is implemented by the dynamic linker. It can only intercept symbols that it processes.

Comment: Why is that a "normal" symbol? What even is a normal symbol? Note that if you look at compiler/linker tools, the compiler generates binary code with so-called symbols (I guess those are what you call normal) and the linker combines them into an executable or library ('*.so"). If you `strip` them, the symbols previously used by the linker are gone. Generally, this sounds like an "XY problem", maybe you'll get better responses if you described your goal instead of asking why your flawed approach doesn't work.

Comment: @123go – 
Be also aware that a function written in C++ without e. g. `extern "C"` will get its name mangled.

Comment: Why do you want to replace __opendirat?

Comment: Sorry for the confusing expression, normal symbols should be local functions. My goals is to replace __opendirat.

Comment: __opendirat can open a dir, I want this function can open /a/b/c and /add/path/a/b/c both when __opendirat is opening /a/b/c. (dirs have the same suffix and /add/path/ is fixed).

Answer (score 0):

The terms that you are using are a bit confusing.

There are two main kinds of symbol visibility. Local (for instance "t" for functions as shown ny `nm`) and global or extern (for instance "T" for functions as shown by `nm`).

Since local functions can only be called from within the library they use static linkage.

Global functions can be called from outside of the library, and so they have dynamic linkage.

It's not possible (at least not with simple techniques like LD_PRELOAD) to replace static functions in dynamic libraries.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems that I need to find another way to figure it out. Sorry for the confusing terms. Normal symbols that I present are exactly the meaning of local function.